# C++ mutex not locking across windows accounts

Tags: c++, winapi, system, mutex

When I run my C++ program the winAPI mutex correctly locks, so if i try to run a second instance it checks if I can open the locked mutex:
`OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, mutexName.c_str());`

I get the expected error:
`mutexName << " is already running on this machine! Aborting!";`

so far so good

The problem is when I have 1 instance of the program running and switch to a different windows account. The mutex should be locked, but when I run a second instance it ignores that the mutex is locked and starts up anyways!

so my question is for this line:

```
 m_hMutex = ::OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, mutexName.c_str());
```

When it is run a second time why does it set m_hMutex != NULL when the second instance is run on the same windows account...

but sets m_hMutex == NULL when the second instance is run on a new account?

In both cases the function parameters are exactly the same, and this code is ran on the D:\

Comment: What do you mean by different windows account? Also I'm fairly sure that mutexes work only on one instance of a program. You'll need another mechanism to do whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: your mutex name must begin with Global\ prefix for be the same in different sessions

Comment: What you're describing is related to "fast user switching", and is done using terminal services sessions. Did you research the kernel object naming requirements for this? I ask because that specific circumstance is called out in [docs for OpenMutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-openmutexw)

Comment: @ShadowMitia if you are using [mutex functions from WINAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexa), they can span multiple processes/users.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each user logged in runs in its own desktop session.  In order to access a *named* kernel object, like a mutex, across user sessions, you need to prefix the object's name with the `Global\` namespace prefix, otherwise you end up creating separate mutex objects locally in each user session.

Per the [`CreateMutex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexa) and [`OpenMutex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-openmutexw) documentations:

> The name can have a "Global" or "Local" prefix to explicitly create the object in the global or session namespace. The remainder of the name can contain any character except the backslash character. For more information, see [Kernel Object Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TermServ/kernel-object-namespaces).

And per the [Kernel Object Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TermServ/kernel-object-namespaces) documentation:

> The separate client session namespaces enable multiple clients to run the same applications without interfering with each other. For processes started under a client session, the system uses the session namespace by default. However, these processes can use the global namespace by prepending the `"Global\"` prefix to the object name. For example, the following code calls `CreateEvent and creates an event object named CSAPP in the global namespace:
>
> ```
> CreateEvent( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "Global\\CSAPP" );
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Another use of the global namespace is for applications that use named objects to detect that there is already an instance of the application running in the system across all sessions. **This named object must be created or opened in the global namespace instead of the per-session namespace**. The more common case of running the application once per session is supported by default because the named object is created in a per session namespace.

Also, you should use `CreateMutex()` instead of `OpenMutex()` to avoid a race condition that would allow another instance of your app to create the mutex before the current instance has a chance to create it. `GetLastError()` will report `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if `CreateMutex()` is successful and the mutex already existed.  Don't call `OpenMutex()` unless `CreateMutex()` reports an `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` error instead, per the `CreateMutex` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexa):

> **If `lpName` matches the name of an existing named mutex object, this function requests the `MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS` access right**. In this case, the `bInitialOwner` parameter is ignored because it has already been set by the creating process.
>
> ...
>
> If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this function call, the return value is a handle to the existing object, `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, `bInitialOwner` is ignored, and the calling thread is not granted ownership. **However, if the caller has limited access rights, the function will fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` and the caller should use the `OpenMutex` function**.

Try something like this:

```
mutexName = "Global\\MyMutexName";

m_hMutex = ::CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, mutexName.c_str());
if ((!m_hMutex) && (GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)) {
    m_hMutex = ::OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, mutexName.c_str());
}

if (!m_hMutex) {
    ... << mutexName << " cannot be accessed! Aborting!";
    //...
}
else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
    ... << mutexName << " is already running on this machine! Aborting!";
    //...
}
else {
    //...
}
```

Or, on Vista and later, you can use [`CreateMutexEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexexa) instead:

```
mutexName = "Global\\MyMutexName";

m_hMutex = ::CreateMutexEx(NULL, mutexName.c_str(), 0, SYNCHRONIZE);
if (!m_hMutex) {
    ... << mutexName << " cannot be accessed! Aborting!";
    //...
}
else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
    ... << mutexName << " is already running on this machine! Aborting!";
    //...
}
else {
    //...
}
```

Comment: what sense of separate call `OpenMutex` ? just call `CreateMutexEx` with `SYNCHRONIZE` access. also instead mutex we can use say `CreateEventEx` if we need only object existing by not it

Comment: if say that `CreateEventEx` (`CreateMutexEx`) begin from vista - [`ZwCreateEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566423(v=vs.85).aspx)  (`NtCreateMutant`) exist even in win2000

Comment: @RbMm I was not aware that `CreateMutexEx()` (or `CreateEventEx()`) even existed.

Comment: if we create some object only for prevent multiple instance of application run in concurrent - any almost named object  here is ok, not only mutex.because we use not object properties but only it name. in this case event the best object - the smallest and most simply (dont know why mutex usually select for this role). in case event we can use and native (even documented) api `ZwCreateEvent`. usual story when win32 shell less functional compare native. and only begin from vista added extra functional with Ex prefix

Comment: @MichaelKlym and how do you know that exactly? If you prefix the mutex name with `Global` then it WILL use the global namespace, there is no way it couldn't. Which means your tracking code is likely flawed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau how can I see that this process is using a global namespace vs the local?

Comment: Have a look at [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Comment: @MichaelKlym no. It is not suppose to error. That is the whole point. Opening/creating a named mutex that already exists gives you a handle to that mutex. That allows multiple processes to share the same mutex and sync with each other. But you are not interested in syncing, only with existence. So, if you open a mutex and it succeeds, the mutex already existed so exit your app. If you create a mutex and it succeeds, you have to check the error code to know if it already existed or not. I showed that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Windows maintains separate namespaces for various kernel objects.  Objects in one namespace can have the same name as objects in another namespace without interfering with each other.  If you want an object to be shared across all sessions, then you must create it in the global namespace.

**From MSDN**

> The separate client session namespaces enable multiple clients to run the same applications without interfering with each other. For processes started under a client session, the system uses the session namespace by default. However, these processes can use the global namespace by prepending the "Global\" prefix to the object name.

Futher reading: [Kernel Object Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TermServ/kernel-object-namespaces)